# Check AD-users with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, active-directory

I've got a table in MS Access with AD-accounts. Of all the users in this table I want to check in Active Directory if they are present logged in. I've found serveral VBA listings but none will do so far.

Can somebody help me with this?

I'm using a module in MS Access to do this check.

Thank you very much for your help.